# Ubuntu Server Error in network definition: expected scalar / Identation error?

Tags: networking

Trying config de network in Ubuntu Server

i use nano

text:

```
network:
  version:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
       dhcp: no
       adresses: [172.00.000.000/24]
       gateway: [172.00.000.1]
       nameservers:
          addressess:
          - 172.00.000.2
          - 172.00.000.3
```

When i try :   sudo netplan apply

ERROR

```
Error im network definition: espected scalar
       gateway4: [172.00.000.1]
```

if i remove square bracket in gateway

```
ERROR: Ivalid YAML: inconsistent identation: 
   #   gateway4: 172.00.000.1
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: can you please use code blocks so we can see what the formatting looks like? you can use ``` on the lines above and below your code so that it will be formatted in monospace.

Comment: also you have many spelling errors, and we can't tell which ones are only here and which may be present in the original file. Can you please triple-check to be sure this is *exactly* what you have in your file, and fix your formatting? Can you also explain what you're trying to do, exactly, and what you need help with (ie ask an actual question)?

Answer (score 1):

The error you got "expected scalar gateway4:" means that it expected a single value not in [], so removing the brackets was the correct solution. The second error about inconsistent indentation came because YAML is *very* picky about exactly how you indent all the lines, and you have to re-check your indentation to be sure it's correct and consistent.

This *may* work, not tested (with spelling mistakes fixed):

```
network:
  version:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp: no
      addresses: [172.00.000.000/24]
      gateway4: 172.00.000.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.00.000.2
        - 172.00.000.3
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I try! now the error is: Ivalid YAML : inconsisten identation:     #   gateway4: 172.00.000.1

Comment: why do you have a # on that line?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Esther's answer, let me point out that the `gateway4` and  `gateway6` options are [deprecated](https://netplan.io/reference/#common-properties-for-all-device-types), and should (for future reference) instead be replaced with default routes - like in [this example](https://netplan.io/examples/#using-dhcp-and-static-addressing):

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            addresses:
                - 10.10.10.2/24
            nameservers:
                search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
                addresses: [10.10.10.1, 1.1.1.1]
            routes:
                - to: default
                  via: 10.10.10.1
```

Comment: Thanks Artur and Esther! There´s some progress ! ahahaahaha . Now i have another issue:   The owerwriting error message was: /etc/netplan/oo-install-config.waml:13:10 Error in network definition: unicast route mus include both a "to" and "via" ip - to: default .... what i do wrong? Thanks!!!!!